# The missing category of (constructive) logic

Tags: logic, category-theory

It is well-known that the types in a given programming language form a category, based on Set, with their functions as morphisms.

It is also well-known that any program is basically a proof in constructive logic - the result is called in Curry–Howard correspondence and it is used in theorem prover software like Coq and Agda.

Doesn't, then, constructive logic form a category, in its own right? The objects are logical assertions, the morphisms are implications and True and False are, as in Coq, the initial and terminal object? And if yes, why isn't that category defined anywhere?

I am asking this is because it seems weird to me that many people talk about the connection between logic and Category theory, but as far as I know no one formalizes it.

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you want. Do you have any application in mind? Are you just asking for he name of this "missing" category (which I don't know)?

Comment: My implicit question is "why isn't that category defined anywhere?"

Comment: I think that it will serve as a great example of a "categorization" of a well-known concept (I think that the main issue with teaching CT is that there are too few examples).

Comment: Regarding the first sentence: http://math.andrej.com/2016/08/06/hask-is-not-a-category/

Comment: OK, I know that Haskell is not a real category, due to the existence of bottom values, but I think that a subset of Haskell is a category. Am I wrong? And is this why logic also can't be thought as a category?

Comment: Please remove the wrong assertion pointed out by @Dap. Especially given that it does not impact your question in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the "term model" or [syntactic category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/syntactic+category) of a type theory. This is defined in *Sketches of an Elephant: A Topos Theory Compendium* D1.4.

This will in general distinguish between proofs - otherwise you just get a poset called the Lindenbaum–Tarski algebra. This is a Heyting algebra if your theory obeys the axioms of intuitionistic logic.

Comment: So my category would be called, something like `Con(Intui)` in which an object would be a set of assertions, for example `(A -> B, A)` and a morphism would convert one set of assertions to another, like 
`(A -> B, A) -> (A)`. Right?

Comment: After reading your second sentence, indeed using category theory for that would be overkill, since in logic we are not interested in the multiple ways in which one set of assertions follows from another.

Comment: @BobbyMarinoff "...in logic, we are not interested in the multiple ways in which one set of assertions follows from another..." This is a bold assertion! There is a whole branch of logic that actually cares for this. Martin-Löf type theory and Homotopy of type theory wouldn't even exist otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I mostly think of these comments as questions, although I didn't formulate them as such.